# Why do some "Ask Question" buttons on some sites not stand out and aren't attractive

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, design, action-buttons

I have this question after reading an article of Dmitry Fadeyev, the designer of ux.SE ([Designing UX Exchange](http://usabilitypost.com/2011/04/22/designing-ux-exchange/)) (I was linked to his blog in [this question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/why-doesnt-ux-se-have-much-drawing-on-the-header?noredirect=1#comment4196_1795)). In his blog, he wrote:

> Because it’s a new community, it’s important to get people to ask questions and participate. For this reason the “Add Question” button needed its own styling to stand and attract the eye.

I recall that in some sites, the *Ask Question* buttons don't stand out from other buttons, and therefore don't get much attractive. Is this because in these sites we don't encourage people to ask?

Some examples:

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

And the meta.SE as you can see it for yourself.

Comment: do you consider the **Ask Question** in beta sites being bold to be standing out, or do you think they should stand out more? I've found that [Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)'s, [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)'s, [Bicycle](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)'s, [Super User](http://superuser.com/)'s Ask Question stands out. Based on my preliminary findings, I'd say some sites are status-bydesign that way, while others it's just a coincidence

Comment: See [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) for an extreme (and fun!! :) counter-example.

Comment: Awesome question, and the ux.stackexchange site is a prime example, see my post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250754/make-ask-question-stand-out?noredirect=1#comment818520_250754